# Vuforia About UserDefinedTargetBuilder Android

Tags: android, augmented-reality, vuforia

We are making a android app with AR features.
We want to use (preshot) album photo in android phone as our image target, then we can detect the preshot photo features in the later camera mode.

Q:
How can we use album photos as image target (user-defined target or any ways without uploading to the cloud and we can do it in the background automatically)?

Thanks! We really need the help!